# Apache camel mail check if no message is fetched

Tags: email, apache-camel, message, fetch

Using Apache Camel, I am fetching an email inbox every 15 minutes and routing emails body to a rest endpoint. Everything is working as it should. 
Here's the declaration of my  Poller:

```
        from(mailServer + "?" +
            "username=" + mailUsername + "&" +
            "password=" + mailPassword + "&" +
            "consumer.delay=" + EVERY_15_MINUTES)
            .routeId("mainPoller")
            .filter(exchange -> exchange.getIn().getHeader("subject", StringUtils.EMPTY, String.class).contains(mailSubject))
            .to("activemq:send.details");
```

Now what I need to do is, if no message were fetched (because no new emails were received) I want to log a message..
How can I check if 0 message were fetched?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **sendEmptyMessageWhenIdle** option

> Camel 2.9: If the polling consumer did not poll any files, you can
>   enable this option to send an empty message (no body) instead.

http://camel.apache.org/polling-consumer.html (pop3 and imap are scheduled poll components)

```
    from(mailServer + "?" +
        "username=" + mailUsername + "&" +
        "password=" + mailPassword + "&" +
        "consumer.delay=" + EVERY_15_MINUTES+
        "&sendEmptyMessageWhenIdle=true")
        .routeId("mainPoller")
        .filter(exchange -> exchange.getIn().getHeader("subject", StringUtils.EMPTY, String.class).contains(mailSubject))
        .to("activemq:send.details");
```